# android KSOAP2 HttpsTransport warning End mothd

Tags: android, warnings, ksoap2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [KSOAP never timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489671/ksoap-never-timeout)

I am successfully consuming a web service using KSOAP2, but eclipse is giving me the following warning message;

```
(org.ksoap2.transport.KeepAliveHttpsTransportSE$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
```

while it is not causing any problems, I would like to find a way of making the message go away and make Eclipse happy, has anyone found a solution to this?

Comment: If u want to make eclipse happy(as u said) first post some  code and the corresponding errors/problems ur getting so that ppl can understand

Comment: And yes next time do want @Raghu said

Answer (score 0):

Use these `@SuppressWarnings` before the warning