# call a web service from android app

Tags: android, service, web, ksoap2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android KSOAP2 HttpsTransport warning End mothd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201100/android-ksoap2-httpstransport-warning-end-mothd)

i build a simple soap web service to Netbeans. Now i am trying to call that web service from my android application in Eclipse. I use ksoap2 and i run the android app to a real device not to emulator.I have this warning:

> Dx warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   (org.ksoap2.transport.KeepAliveHttpsTransportSE$1) that doesn't come with an
>   associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>   this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The warning is ok (I get the same warning).

I think your strings are wrong, they must be:

```
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://service.hello.com";
private static String URL="http://79.107.216.7:8080/HelloWebApplication/HelloWS/";
private static String METHOD_NAME = "hello";
private static String SOAP_ACTION = NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME;
```

And if this line gives you an error

```
SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
```

try this:

```
Object response = envelope.getResponse();
```

Comment: @enmarc Thank you very much for your time and for your response. That was my mistake and now is working correct.The warning is ok.