# Handling timeout while using Ksoap2 in android

Tags: android, timeout, ksoap2, handlers

I am calling a method of another class from my activity that calls a webservice using ksoap2. I want to handle timeout for this. If the method takes more than 10 seconds to execute, then I need to show an alert dialog indicating that the process was not successful.

I tried using the timeout value as follows:

```
HttpsTransportSE transport = new HttpsTransportSE(URL,TIMEOUT);
```

but ksoap2 is ignoring the timeout for some reason. I'm using ksoap2 2.6.5.

Is there any way where in I can execute the method for 10 seconds and then display the appropriate dialog box indicating a success or failure in android?

Comment: What is TIMEOUT value? Is it 10000?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There still seems to be an open issue with HttpTransportSE ignoring the timeout value in some situations. 
See this related [link](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/issues/detail?id=60&q=httpTransportse%20timeout).

However, a solution for this involved modification of the existing `ksoap2 API`.

Thanks to the developers at [Lightsoftai](http://www.lightsoftai.com/?p=707) you can now add timeout to `HttpTransportSE` using the following code:

**Note** : *You can use ksoap2 API version 2.5.2 or greater for this*

```
       /**
       * Creates instance of HttpTransportSE with set url
       *
       * @param url 
       *             the destination to POST SOAP data
       */
         public HttpTransportSE(String url) {
         super(url);
         }

       /**
      * Creates instance of HttpTransportSE with set url
      *
      * @param url
      *            the destination to POST SOAP data
      * @param timeout
      *               timeout for connection and Read Timeouts (milliseconds)
       */
       public HttpTransportSE(String url, int timeout) {
       super(url, timeout);
          }
```

You can download the jar file for the same from [here](http://www.lightsoft.se/_lightsoft/wp-content/plugins/download-monitor/download.php?id=1).

Also refer [ksoap never timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489671/ksoap-never-timeout).

Hope it helps.

Comment: can u help to say, what is the min and max timeout ParthDoshi.

Comment: @Parth Doshi the  Download link is broken Now..!!